# c++ and link to lapack

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, lapack

I have several files which I need to compile together as following in my makefile (names are dummy now):

```
compile:
        g++ prog1.cpp func1.cpp func2.cpp func3.cpp -L/usr/lib/ -lmkl_lapack64 -lmkl 
        -lguide -lpthread -o output_ready.out
```

When I do make compile, then I get the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmkl_lapack64                                                                                                                                                
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmkl                                                                                                                                                         
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lguide                                                                                                                                                       
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status                                                                                                                                                    
make: *** [compile] Error 1
```

This program was correctly compiled in another machine previously.

Q: How can I check the path for lapack lib if they are correct? How should I fix them?
The libraries are installed (not sure if with the right path).

Any helpful comment is highly appreciated.
R

Comment: How did you install lapack?

Comment: good question. I did not do it myself, our admin did who is away now!

Comment: You should ask the admin... `find / -name "libmkl_lapack64.*"` <-- I take no responsibility if that goes wrong, especially if you add `-exec`.

Answer (score 1):

The only path where he looks for the lapack libs is `/usr/lib` - since that's the only dircetory you specified for the linker. If the libs are installed in another location you will have to find it out and

- provide that location to the linker via another `-L` parameter,
- or move the libs to `/usr/lib`

so the linker can find the libs.

Comment: Thanks. But seems that they are there because when I "locate liblapack.a" it gives me the path as /usr/lib. I wonder about those " /usr/bin/ld:" : what do they mean?

Comment: @Reza `liblapack.a != libmkl_lapack64.a`

Comment: Seems that I do not have this one installed (or at least I dont find it).

Comment: `/usr/bin/ld` is just your linker, the one that's complaining about not finding the libs ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need `-L/usr/lib` as I believe the compiler already knows to look there for libraries. That said, you do need `-L<path to where lapack libraries are>` if they were not installed in a standard location.

Comment: please see my reply concerning the path.

Comment: You could use the `find` command as suggested by @AlexChamberlain. Or you could go to the lapack project site and see if they have installation instructions that specify the default install location or recommended paths.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would have suggested you to check if libraries are installed in correct directories, as you planned yourself. An obvious way to do this is just to cd `/usr/lib` and see whether there are any lapack libraries (you will notice them at once).

If everything is installed where it should have been, I would suggest you to compile with

```
-I /usr/local/include/lapackpp/
```

for headers, and

```
-L /usr/local/lib -llapackpp
```

for libraries, as all lapack libraries should be accessed through it.

Also, are you sure you want to look for libraries in `/usr/lib`, but not in `/usr/local/lib`? I guess this is OS/settings specific, though.

Finally, some time ago I have had similar problem to the one you have and found a good and explicit explanation on this website. :-)

Answer (score 0):

An excellent way to find the correct compiler and linker flags based on your OS, architecture, etc. is using the Intel online tool, which you can find here:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor.

To access it, you need to login to the Intel website.